# ActionChains doesn't work trying to hover over element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, mousehover

I'm scraping http://www.nowgoal.com

In the main page,if you scroll down, there is a row named results, and below that all matches of the day already finished. If you hover your mouse over the score, a detail table appears.

This is the html for when you hover

[Hovered table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r9zK.png)

And this, for when it is not hovered

[Unhovered table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YJsp.png)

Well, let's say I get a list of all the nodes, and that I try with the first one

```
node=nodes[0]
```

If I do

```
score=node.find_element_by_css('.red')
```

I get the score element on which you need to hover. Then I try

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(score).perform()
TabScore=browser.find_element_by_id('winScore')
print(TabScore.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

And I get

```
>> <div id="winScore" style="position:absolute; z-index:8;top:100px;left:100px;visibility:hidden;" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('winScore','','show')" onmouseout="hiddendetail()"></div>
```

Which is the node for when it is unhovered, so there must be a problem with the ActionChains. Weird thing is if I recall right, I made it work this way a while ago, so the only two possible explanations are that either something is wrong with ActionChains, or that I changed laptops and this windows works different from the old one (10 versus I think it was Vista).

Comment: Have you tried adding a brief pause between hover and scraping the page? My guess is that it takes a moment to display the table.

Comment: I tried `time.sleep(20)` between ActionChains and find_element to get the actual table. Still the same problem as if the node weren't hovered at all.

Comment: One issue you might be running into is that your locator isn't specific enough. You really want "td.red". Go into the Chrome devtools and use `$$(".red")` and look at the elements returned. The first one is My Games count which is in red. "td.red" returns only the scores you want. I'm still having an issue with getting the hover to work but maybe it will help you. I'm using Java while you are using Python.

Comment: I just posted the part that is wrong. Before that, I have created a list of nodes, and into each node, that search is unique. If you do `.text` you get the result of the match, and if you click it, it opens a new tab. So it is already checked that I'm indeed pointing to the right element.